# Download File Unix - Auth Dialog Popup

Tags: unix, authentication, curl, amazon-ec2, wget

I'm trying to download a file to an AWS EC2 instance (based on AWS Linux AMI) from the internet through the shell.

**Source File Location:** Secure site that prompts for login dialog when downloading in browser

**Destination File Location:** AWS EC2 instance

I tried the variations of the below Unix commands to no effect

**wget with Auth:**

```
wget  -O dummyfile.zip https://dummyurl.com/dummyfile.zip --user=MY_USER_ID --password=MY_PASSWORD --auth-no-challenge
```

**Result:**

```
Resolving dummyurl.com (dummyurl.com)... XX.XX.XX.XXX
Connecting to dummyurl.com (dummyurl.com)|XX.XX.XX.XXX|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-07-27 19:23:55 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

**cURL with Auth:**

```
curl -o dummyfile.zip -u MY_USER_ID:MY_PASSWORD https://dummyurl.com/dummyfile.zip
```

**Result:**

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "https%3A//dummyurl.com/dummyfile.zip" on this server.<P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**cURL with Auth in URL:**

```
curl -o dummyfile.zip https://MY_USER_ID:MY_PASSWORD@dummyurl.com/dummyfile.zip
```

**Result:**

```
Same as above
```

The download succeeds in the browser after I authenticate in the below popup.
How do I download this file by performing a successful authentication?

[image: Authentication Popup Dialog in Browser]

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you achieve your user case using wget in unix.

```
# Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.

   wget ‐‐cookies=on ‐‐save-cookies cookies.txt ‐‐keep-session-cookies ‐‐post-data ‘user=un&password=password’ http://example.com/file.zip


   # Now grab the file using below

   wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies cookies.txt \
    -p https://dummyurl.com/dummyfile.zip
```

Comment: The first wget gives me `ERROR 403: Forbidden.`

Comment: Even with the `keep-session-cookies`, it's the same response - `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden`

Comment: Can you try using http instead of https and see what happens?

Comment: Let us try Curl :) Use this curl -u username:password https://dummyurl.com/dummyfile.zip and see if it works

Comment: Tried it earlier. Also re-tried now. Responds with an HTML (given in question) - `<H1>Access Denied</H1>`. I thought this would be a simple wget/curl flag for handling popup auth, but the world doesn't seem to work that way. Thanks for trying though - @error2007s :)

Comment: How is the SSL set up for that dummy URL is it on a Load balancer or on a server?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a direct server, but there's no way I can be sure of it. 
The SSL is using sha256RSA and it's not in my control. The SSL certificate is the same as the ones in all SAP sites though. Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/107063/any-way-to-determine-if-a-load-balancer-is-being-used-on-a-site

Comment: It's still `ERROR 403: Forbidden.` :(

Comment: Yes. I did. It's not the certificate check that's going wrong though. The Auth process is not registering from the looks of it. I get the forbidden message for both the commands. The cookies.txt is empty except for the auto-generated comments.

Comment: In my answer first command are you adding ' before and after the ‘user=un&password=password’ don't add that just use user=un&password=password and try running the command.

Comment: Without that it's a syntax error - `wget: missing URL`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118482/discussion-between-error2007s-and-ashok-felix).